# Exiting C code to R on error

Tags: c, r

What's the best practice for exiting C code on discovery of an error back to R? Package guidance says don't use `exit()`, which makes sense (as you kill everything), but how do you exit to R and indicate an error has occurred. Obviously you could have an error flag in the return vector, but is there a better way?

Comment: Can you cite what says "don't use `error()`"?

Comment: Bah, sorry - typo, I meant `exit` (as in `exit(1)`)

Comment: Then, isn't `error()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Why yes it is - apparently my subconscious knows more than me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `error()`.  It's described in [Section 6.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Error-handling) of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html)... and you should listen to your subconscious more often. ;-)